# I want to know how to make all my elements on a navigation be evenly spaced

Tags: html, css

I want to know how to make all my elements on a navigation be evenly spaced. It's for a school project where I am creating a website and I can't work it out and all the solutions I looked at didn't work.

```
<style>
    div {
      width: 1330px;
      padding: 10px;
      margin: 0; 
      background-color: #212F3D;
      text-align: center;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

You've essentially got two options, using either [`display:flex;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex), or [`display:inline-block;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display).

Flex will ensure that your items are shown end-to-end with the same spacing between each item (*take note of the CSS rule in the example: `justify-content:space-between`*), whereas inline-block can be used to center align your menu items and manually add their spacing with a margin.

I would suggest using flex as it seems better suited to your requirements, [here's a fiddle showing](https://jsfiddle.net/to6y2r9n/) the difference between the two, the examples are below.

## Using Flex:

```css
.header ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display:flex; /* This is the part to focus on */
  flex-wrap: wrap; /* This is the part to focus on */
  justify-content: space-between; /* This is the part to focus on */
  background-color: rgba(25,57,125, 0.8);
}
.header li {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
<ul>
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 2</li>
<li>Item 3 has a long name</li>
<li>Item 4</li>
<li>One more Item</li>
</ul>
```

---

## Using Inline Block

```css
.header ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center; /* This is the part to focus on */
  background-color: rgba(125,57,125, 0.8);
}
.header li {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  padding: 2px;
  display: inline-block; /* This is the part to focus on */
  margin: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
<ul>
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 2</li>
<li>Item 3 has a long name</li>
<li>Item 4</li>
<li>One more Item</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: So im confused how will it change my coding. Im sorry im only in year 9 at school and this is for a project. I dont understand what each different part does. I only started HTML 4 or 5 weeks ago and I know basic HTML but not much else